# I am trying to scrape moderna/pfizer websites to see what dates they released news. Code in R gives the output character(0) and not the datess

Tags: html, date, screen-scraping, rscript

This the code I ran for pfizer and Moderna (package used: 'rvest')

Pfizer:

scrape_url <- "http://www.pfizer.com/news"

webpage <- read_html(scrape_url)

pfizer_newsdates_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.rssDate')

pfizer_newsdates <- html_text(pfizer_newsdates_html)

head(pfizer_newsdates)

---

For moderna-

scrape_url2 <- "https://investors.modernatx.com/news-releases"

webpage2 <- read_html(scrape_url)

moderna_newsdates_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.nir-widget--news--date-time')

moderna_newsdates <- html_text(moderna_newsdates_html)

head(moderna_newsdates)

Answer (score 0):

For Pfizer, use the right class. For Moderna, use httr as an user-agent header is required

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(httr)
library(stringr)

moderna_dates <- read_html(httr::GET('https://investors.modernatx.com/news-releases', add_headers("User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>% 
  html_nodes('.nir-widget--news--date-time') %>% html_text() %>% str_squish()

pfizer_dates <- read_html('https://www.pfizer.com/news') %>% 
  html_nodes('.views-field-field-press-release-date') %>% html_text()
```

Comment: I got the output in a series format. Can I do the Time series with this output in next step? if yes how?